# How to setText from a JTextField to a JLabel upon clicking a JButton "enter"

Tags: java, swing

I thought it was something like this(but turns out it doesn't do anything!):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String labelID = e.getActionCommand();
    JTextField EnterName = new JTextField();
    JLabel NameINLabel = new JLabel();
    String random = new String();
    random = EnterName.getText();

    if (labelID == "Enter Name"){
        NameINLabel.setText(random);
    }
}
```

My button works perfectly, nothing is wrong with that. But when i click the button "Enter Name", nothing happens to the jlabel. HELP PLZ

Comment: Why are the JTextField and JLabel declared inside the event handler? Are you trying to make them visible when you click the button? My sincere doubt is: does it work?

Comment: There are several problems with your code: 1. You never add the JTextField and JLabel to a content pane, so they'll never be visible.  2. You create EnterName with the empty string as its text, so EnterName.getText() will always return the empty string.  3. You should not use == to compare the contents of strings.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Comment: I'm trying to make the JLabel visible when the button is clicked. 
I added everything to the content pane already. I just didn't show it. 
Yea i'm pretty bad with naming things.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with vaisakh, you need to declare your components outside the event handler. You also need to add them to the content pane. 
For compare content of string you should use the `.equals("")` or `compareTo("")` methods.

Comment: I did declare components outside the handler. I did add them to the content pane. I just didn't show that part.